# ElasticSearch Create Index, index already exists exception

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am trying a simple new index on elasticsearch cloud with postman (elastic v.52)
But i cant see this index in my control panel.

I also received an "index not found" exception when I tried to send a delete request to the server.

I do not know what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas ?

Create index request:
[image]

Delete request:

[image]

Comment: Can you list down available indexes using GET /_cat/indices?v  ??

Comment: Yes, i did. Returned index not found exception again.

Comment: May be you have tried wrong request.Please try request from this page https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_list_all_indices.html

Comment: Thanks, but i can't see my create request index name on this result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. It's index name uppercase problem. But elastic result don't explation this on exception details.

My wrong old index name "i_serdarTest"

New accepted index name "i_serdartest"

Comment: Elasticsearch does tell you that it doesn't allow uppercase letters in index names. Maybe your REST client is messing things up? I've testet with 5.6, but 5.2 should be the same. The error includes the following: `"type": "invalid_index_name_exception", "reason": "Invalid index name [i_serdarTest], must be lowercase",`

Comment: Maybe you right. Because i received true exception messages on kibana rest console.